# How do I setup ingress for HashiCorp Vault UI in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, hashicorp-vault, nginx-ingress

I have just installed an HashiCorp Vault on my Kubernetes cluster using. 
I want it to work through my existing ingress controller so I have created a new ingress rule using the yaml below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vault-ingress
  namespace: vault
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /vault
        backend:
          serviceName: vault
          servicePort: 8200
```

To my service which runs as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: vault
  labels:
    module: vault
spec:
  selector:
    module: vault
  ports:
  - port: 8200
    targetPort: 8200
```

However, when I try and access my URL: `http://ingress.domain/vault/ui`
I get empty page with errors

```
13.72.65.96/:24 GET http://ingress.domain/ui/assets/vendor-854d73b9f9351c0ff2e27f8821dfcd09.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
13.72.65.96/:25 GET http://ingress.domain/ui/assets/vault-f8ac2e61e061b2fb490b6ad79fcd5c1f.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
13.72.65.96/:15 GET http://ingress.domain/ui/assets/vendor-895fbba1663c3b4fe68755a3fb7ae7b4.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
13.72.65.96/:16 GET http://ingress.domain/ui/assets/vault-8ed265cce923599eca663b1bb2e4a83f.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
13.72.65.96/:25 GET http://ingress.domain/ui/assets/vault-f8ac2e61e061b2fb490b6ad79fcd5c1f.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon-68e1a9c89026b0efeddf718a48c282a5.png:1 
GET http://ingress.domain/ui/favicon-68e1a9c89026b0efeddf718a48c282a5.png 404 (Not Found)
```

My configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: vault
  labels:
    module: vault
data:
  config.json : '{
    "ui": "true",
    "disable_mlock": "true",
    "api_addr": "http://127.0.0.1:8200/vault",
    "listener": [
        {
            "tcp": {
                "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
                "tls_disable": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: vault
  labels:
    module: vault
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      module: vault
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        module: vault
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vault
        image: vault
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
        -  vault server -config /vault/config/config.json
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        volumeMounts:
          - name: configurations
            mountPath: /vault/config/config.json
            subPath: config.json
        env:
          - name: VAULT_ADDR
            value: "http://localhost:8200/vault/"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8200
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: configurations
          configMap:
            name: vault
```

ow do I setup ingress for Vault UI in Kubernetes?
I have one domain for my Ingress, so the UI (and other services) should be : http://ingress.domain/{service name}. I need the Vault UI http://ingress.domain/vault

Comment: Can try to remove this line from ingress `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` and kubectl apply it. Just give it a try if it works will let you know what was wrong.

Comment: @mchawre didn't help. Now I have 404

Comment: ok can you figure out what is the base path of vault ui. Is it `/ui` or `/vault/ui`

Comment: The base path us /ui

Comment: In that case you might try to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /ui` so that just hitting `http://ingress.domain/vault` will point to `http://ingress.domain/ui`

Comment: I have tried, got error as in question. I need `http://ingress.domain/vault/ui` that will redirect to inner `http://localhost:8200/ui` But it seems not possible because Vault's UI does not support a subpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got response on [Vault forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/vault-tool/Ktu7JGL4wxo):

> this is (currently) not possible. Vault's UI (and API) is not able to
>   work with domain subpathing.